# How to load the quartz properties from the database rather than a quartz property file?

Tags: java, mongodb, quartz-scheduler

```
# Use the MongoDB store
org.quartz.jobStore.class=com.landisgyr.aga.server.quartz.MongoDbJobStore
# MongoDb Host Name
org.quartz.jobStore.addresses=localhost
# Mongo Database name
org.quartz.jobStore.dbName=aga
org.quartz.jobStore.instanceId=jobInstance
# Collection prefix
org.quartz.jobStore.collectionPrefix=quartz.scheduler.
#Threadpool count 

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = AGAQuartzScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 8
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 8
```

How to load the above mentioned properties from a database rather than from a property file.

Comment: Add a database, create a table, read the values.

Comment: How  to pass the values to the StdSchedulerFactory

Comment: I am getting the values from and storing that in a pojo class. Does the field names matter or it can be any field names